# Is it possible to detect comparison of incompatible types with the Java type system?

Tags: java, generics, type-erasure, type-safety, type-systems

I'm trying to write a helper function to compare two types in a typesafe way:

```
typesafeEquals("abc", new Integer(42)); // should not compile
```

My first straightforward attempt failed:

```
<T> boolean typesafeEquals(T x, T y) { // does not work!
    return x.equals(y);
}
```

Well, the problem is that `T` can be deduced to be an `Object`. Now, I wonder if it is impossible to implement `typesafeEquals` in the Java type system.

I know that there are tools like FindBugs find can warn about comparison of incompatible types. Anyway it would be interesting to either see a solution without external tools or an explanation why it is impossible.

---

**Update:** I think the answer is that it is impossible. I have no proof to support that claim, though. Only that it seems to be difficult to come up with a solution that works for all cases.

Some answers come close, but I believe the type system of Java does not support to solve the problem in all generality.

Comment: Is this meant to be used for a different use case? The `equals(..)` method will (should) fail for objects of different types, so what does it matter if you enforce type safety?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Comparing two incompatible types is a common source of bugs. At runtime, equals will always return false but that it likely not what the author intended. IDEs can show warnings but having the compiler detect it at compile time would be nice.

Comment: `Comparable` is type-sensitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to detect comparison of incompatible types with the Java type system?
>   [...]
>   I believe the type system of Java does not support to solve the problem in all generality.

The type system alone cannot do that, at least not in a universal way that would work for all types in absolute generality, because it has no way to tell what your types do in their `equals` implementations (as already said in supercat's answer), a `Foo` could accept to be compared to a `Bar`, that logic is inscribed in the code itself, so, not available for the compiler to check.

---

That being said, for a "restricted" definition of "type-safe", if you can *declare what you expect for each use*, your own approach was almost there, just make it static, call it using the class name, and explicitly specify the expected type:

```
public class TypeSafe {

    public static <T> boolean areEqual(T x, T y) {
        return x.equals(y);
    }

    void test() {
        TypeSafe.areEqual("a", 1); // Compiles because no restriction is present.
                                   // Both are resolved to Serializable
                                   // [there is not only "Object" in common ;)]

        TypeSafe.<CharSequence>areEqual("a", 1); // Does not compile
        //                                   ^
        //          Found: int, required: java.lang.CharSequence
    }
}
```

Similar to Makoto's answer, without passing the type as argument, and to Jeremy's, without creating a new object. <sub>(upvoted both.)</sub>

Although it would be slightly misleading because `TypeSafe.<Number>areEqual(1f, 1d)` compiles but returns false. It can give a false sense of meaning "are those 2 numbers equivalent?" (this is not what it does). So you have to know what you're doing...

---

Now, even if you compare two `Long` values, one could be an epoch-based timestamp in milliseconds, and the other in seconds, 2 identical raw values would not be "equal".

With Java 8 we have [type annotations](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/java-8s-new-type-annotations), and the compiler can be instrumented with an annotation processor to perform additional checks based on those annotations (see [checker framework](https://checkerframework.org/)).

Say we have these methods that return durations in milliseconds and in seconds, as specified with annotations `@m` and `@s` ([provided by framework](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#units-checker)) :

```
@m long getFooInMillis() { /* ... */ }
@s long getBarInSeconds() { /* ... */ }
```

<sub>(Of course in that case it's probably best to use proper types in the first place, like `Instant` or `Duration`... but please ignore that for a minute)</sub>

With that, you can be even more specific about that constraint you pass as generic type argument to your method, using checker framework and annotations:

```
long t1 = getFooInMillis();
long t2 = getBarInSeconds();

TypeSafe.<Long>areEqual(t1, t2);    // OK, just as we've seen earlier

TypeSafe.<@m Long>areEqual(t1, t2); // Error: incompatible types in argument
//                         ^^  ^^
// found   : @UnknownUnits long
// required: @m Long

@m long t1m = getFooInMillis();
@s long t2s = getBarInSeconds();
@m long t2m = getFooInMillis();

TypeSafe.<Long>areEqual(t1m, t2s);    // OK

TypeSafe.<@m Long>areEqual(t1m, t2s); // Error: incompatible types in argument
//                              ^^^
// found   : @s long
// required: @m Long

TypeSafe.<@m Long>areEqual(t1m, t2m); // OK
```

Comment: Thank you for your excellent answer. I certainly liked the other answers so far, as each one brought some new idea, but your answer is the most comprehensive.

Answer (score 6):

Adding a third parameter - the `Class<T>` type to your method - will help with this sort of issue.  As you say, you can get an `Object` from `T`; unless you add bounds to it, it won't ever be able to identify anything other than `Object`.

While adding the class type will force you to put it in every time you want to use the method, it enforces the compiler and implied contract that you're comparing them equal as if they are a certain class.

```
<T> boolean typesafeEquals(T x, T y, Class<T> clazz) {
    return x.equals(y);
}
```

---

Do note that this kind of checking is a bit of an overreaction from the perspective of the developer.  It should be the case that two objects which are *not* equivalent should simply return `false`.

Given the requirement of it being a drop-in replacement for `Object.equals`, that is simply impossible given the well-established loose type safety around the method as it is.  While generics would be an ideal way to solve this, generics existed in Java 5, whereas `equals` was there from the beginning.

Comment: Is the following acceptable? `typesafeEquals("abc", new Integer(42), Object.class);` We are explicitly saying we want `Object`.

Comment: The compiler can't make any checks on it, but it should give the developer a queasy feeling; I'm calling a typesafe equals method with two objects that are related by `Object`.  Why should I be doing that?

Comment: What if the code is generated? Which would be a perfect use case for static checks... `typesafeEquals("abc", new Integer(42))` is weird as well to write...

Comment: You have to be a bit more careful than this, although I'd expect your dynamically generated code to at least share a superclass.

Comment: If you're going to force the caller to explicitly declare the type then @Jeremy Grand's solution is better since it actually imposes type safety in the compiler.

Answer (score 5):

Asking an instance of `Apple` whether it is equal to a particular instance of `Orange` should not cause it any trouble.  It should simply observe that because it does not consider itself equal to any objects which are not of type `Apple`, and because it was given a reference to something that isn't of type `Apple`, it does not consider itself equal to the passed in object.

Further, certain interfaces have contracts which require implementations them to consider themselves equal to any other implementations meeting certain criteria.  It would thus be possible for two objects which are of unrelated types to both implement an interface which requires that the two objects report each other as equal.  Even if the types of the references have no interface in common, unless at least one is sealed it would be possible for instances of types derived from them to share an interface which would compel a reciprocal equality relationship.

Consequently, while there are certainly cases where static analysis could reveal that the objects identified by references of two different classes cannot possibly consider themselves equal, the level of static analysis required would be far beyond anything the generic type system could possibly encapsulate [among other things, it would require examination of the code in the different types' `equals` methods].

I would suggest that while it might in theory be nice if the compiler could identify cases where code tried to compare things that couldn't possibly be equal, the way that rules about `equals` are defined (including the fact that it's permissible--and in some cases required--for instances of unrelated classes to compare themselves equal to each other) means that in general what you seek isn't possible.  If it's possible to ask an instance of `Apple` whether it's equal to any particular `Fruit`, then it must be possible to ask it whether it's equal to any particular instance of any type derived from `Fruit`.  The `Apple` shouldn't care if the question is silly; it should simply answer it.

Comment: I tend to agree with you.

Answer (score 2):

What you've tried won't work because `T` is ambiguous and the compiler will try to make the code compile (by interpreting it to be `Object`). You need to force it a little bit by explicitly setting the type you want to check.

[Makoto's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26551490/7573818) is very good for that.

And, if you can cope with using another object, you can also use the following :

```
public class EqualsHelper<T> {
    public boolean areEquals(T one, T another){
        if(one == null){
            return another == null;
        }
        return one.equals(another);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EqualsHelper<String> stringHelper = new EqualsHelper<>();
    stringHelper.areEquals("hello","world");  // compile
    stringHelper.areEquals("hello",1);        // doesn't
}
```

Comment: Good idea that might satisfy OP's definition of "type safe". This also works with subtypes (for situations where that is desirable): `EqualsHelper<Type> h = new EqualsHelper<>();` then `h.areEquals(subType1, subType2)` compiles (with Java 8).

Comment: This works, but it breaks the [general contract of `equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)).

Comment: @Makoto in what way does it break the contract of equals ? Because of the null == null returning true ? That isn't breaking the contract of equals. null equals null is necessarily unspecified because it makes no sense. However, I'd be more shocked if a `areEquals(null,null)` returned false.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
public static <T, E extends T> boolean typesafeEquals(T x, E y) {
    return x.equals(y);
}
```

Of course it will compile for subclasses of T, but that kinda makes sense, by the principle of substitution. The only problem is that it enforces an order on the arguments, so it should be renamed it "isAssignable".

edit: Or if you go for strict equality, call it twice while switching arguments:

```
typesafeEquals("", 1); // doesn't compile
typesafeEquals(1, ""); // doesn't compile
typesafeEquals(base, child); // compile
typesafeEquals(child, base); // doesn't compile
```

Comment: How will this help? Whatever you give as `x` and `y`, `T` can be `Object` and `E` can be whatever the class of `y` is.

Comment: It helps by solving cases like OP's example. And if you give an Object, it gives you an answer compliant with type assignation  rules.

Comment: Interesting approach. It will detect most simple errors.

Comment: Call it twice with switched arguments and you'll enforce strict equality.

Comment: Your example fails like OP's in Java 8, which has better type inference.

Answer (score 0):

You have several options here.

## Use a Type Safety Interface/Class

This is similar to passing directly to the method, except the extra scope prevents the compiler from cheesing the generic type to Object.

```
static interface ITypeSafe<T> {
    public default boolean typeSafeEquals(T o) {
        return equals(o);
    };
}

static class TypeSafeEquals<T> {

    public static <A, B extends A> boolean stypeSafeEquals(B o1, B o2) {
        return o1.equals(o2);// tse(o2, o1);
    }

    private boolean typeSafeEquals(T o1, T o2) {
        return o1.equals(o2);
    }
}
```

## Use Annotations for compiler hooks

You can also add a [compiler hook](http://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/core-java-tutorial/java-se-annotation-processing-api/annotation-processor-validation/) using annotations, and then use annotations to flag for type safety. This probably won't work for large teams though as it does require extra project settings set to work, but by far the most versatile. (I can't include example here because it is complicated and I don't fully understand it.)

## Check in unit tests

You can use development test lines like [assert](https://www.javatpoint.com/assertion-in-java) `assert (o1.getClass() == o2.getClass());` to check during unit tests that always true assumptions aren't violated. (You should be doing this anyways) Just make sure these lines are executed during development and not during production. (This should be an easier alternative to the compiler hook)

Answer (score -1):

First of all functions overloading :)

```
typesafeEquals(Integer, Integer);
typesafeEquals(int, int);
typesafeEquals(String, String);
...
```

Second is

```
<N extends Number> typesafeEquals(N, N);
<C extends CharSequence> typesafeEquals(C, C);
...
```

Comment: How do you intend to offer overload covering ALL classes?

Comment: @AjahnCharles nohow. But this is called overloading and could be used in many ways. Moreover, the accepted answer is good, you have one method for all types. From the other side, your code would be very ugly with them because you should manage explicitly all types in all places where you call this one method. So tastes dependent.